# Why isn't there a generic type constraint for TMiddleware on UseMiddlewareExtensions.UseMiddleware()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[This article](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/writing-custom-middleware-in-asp-net-core-1-0/) explains that TMiddleware type must have specific items, like:

- private property of type RequestDelegate;
- async task called Invoke;

**Question 01**: Where is this officially documented? [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usemiddlewareextensions.usemiddleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_UseMiddlewareExtensions_UseMiddleware_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_System_Type_System_Object___) on MS docs doesn't specify it.

**Question 02**: Even if it is documented somewhere, why MS chose not to add a generic type constraint using an interface specifying what's needed for TMiddleware?

Note: I can do what I need without knowing these answers, but still worth asking.

Comment: Official documentation here should be of interest to you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Note the part where it explicitly states what a middleware class must include

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Nkosi. Why wouldn't they use an interface or generic type constraint forcing those requirements, instead of leaving it open?

Comment: There is an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.imiddleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but it is not mandatory, By not having the constraint it is more generic and follows more of a "by convention" approach

Comment: Got it, thanks. Thanks for pointing out the interface too.